# Area 51 notification does not disappear if you visit the FAQ from the topbar

Tags: bug, area-51, notifications, top-bar, site-faq

Area 51 has a notification for first-time visitors, which disappears if you click "X" or click on the FAQ link in the notification.

However, if you click on "faq" in the topbar (between "discuss" and "users"), the notification will not disappear:

[image]

As you can see, I'm on the FAQ and the notification is still visible. Why should the topbar button be any different from the link in the notification?